# HereMaps api getdirections invalid operation error on android

Tags: android, get, maps, directions

I am trying to get directions between two point in heremaps. But in routeManagerListener, I get an error that is INVALID_OPERATION. please help.
This is my listener.

```
    private RouteManager.Listener routeManagerListener = new RouteManager.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onCalculateRouteFinished(RouteManager.Error error, List<RouteResult> list) {
        if (error == RouteManager.Error.NONE &&
                list.get(0).getRoute() != null) {
            // create a map route object and place it on the map
            mapRoute = new MapRoute(list.get(0).getRoute());
            map.addMapObject(mapRoute);

            // Get the bounding box containing the route and zoom in
            GeoBoundingBox gbb = list.get(0).getRoute().getBoundingBox();
            map.zoomTo(gbb, Map.Animation.NONE,
                    Map.MOVE_PRESERVE_ORIENTATION);

            textViewResult.setText(
                    String.format("Route calculated with %d maneuvers.",
                            list.get(0).getRoute().getManeuvers().size()));
        }else{
        textViewResult.setText(
                String.format("Route calculation failed: %s",
                        error.toString()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(int i) {
        textViewResult.setText(
                String.format("... %d percent done ...", i));
    }
};
```

and this is getDirections method.

```
public void getDirections(View view) {
    // 1. clear previous results
    textViewResult.setText("");
    if (map != null && mapRoute != null) {
        map.removeMapObject(mapRoute);
        mapRoute = null;
    }

    // 2. Initialize RouteManager
    RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager();

    // 3. Select routing options via RoutingMode
    RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();

    RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
    routeOptions.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.CAR);
    routeOptions.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);
    routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);

    // 4. Select Waypoints for your routes
    // START: Nokia, Burnaby
    routePlan.addWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(49.1966286, -123.0053635));

    // END: Airport, YVR
    routePlan.addWaypoint(new GeoCoordinate(49.1947289, -123.1762924));


    // 5. Retrieve Routing information via RouteManagerListener
    RouteManager.Error error =
            routeManager.calculateRoute(routePlan, routeManagerListener);
    if (error != RouteManager.Error.NONE) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Route calculation failed with: " + error.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

and how ı call this method:

```
    bgetDirection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getDirections(view);
        }
    });
```

Comment: In this program, have you initialized the MapEngine for the HERE SDK before attempting routing? This can be done using the MapEngine object explicitly, or if using the MapFragment, by using the init() method.

Comment: Also, according the documentation, INVALID_OPERATION is returned when "The operation is not allowed at this time because another request is in progress". Is it possible this method is being called multiple times or another routing request is ongoing?

Comment: I have initialized the MapFragment by init. And there is no any other routing req is ongoing. @AndrewJC